# Why is using a URL as filename in Windows Explorer so slow?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When I attach a file in Gmail, add a picture in a StackExchange post, etc., I often use a URL as filename in Windows Explorer:

[image]

It typically takes a few seconds, usually between 5 and 10 seconds. Why is it so slow, whereas downloading the file pointed by the URL takes less than 1 second?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Google Chrome.

Comment: Run this and give me the trace file: http://pastebin.com/9R3Ehbs3

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, but the script gave me a few errors: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kn9gf.png . Any idea?

Comment: replace **Network** with **NETWORKTRACE**. Does this work?

Comment: @magicandre1981 same issue http://i.stack.imgur.com/HMqoa.png :/ it works if I remove NETWORKTRACE though.

Comment: run a cmd.exe and run **xperf -providers k** Do you see Network and Networktrace there or not? If not, run the command without the network flag and give me the file. Maybe I can still see any details.

Comment: have you created the trace?

Comment: is the issue fixed or not?